# How can I make a chrome packaged app which runs in fullscreen at startup?

Tags: google-chrome-app

Currently it seems that the fullscreen ability can only be activated from a user action (mouse/keyboard event). Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 13):

Now, you can just add the `state:"fullscreen"` property on your main .js:

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(
    function() {
        chrome.app.window.create('index.html',
            {
                state: "fullscreen",
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Make sure you don't add `resizable: false` or `bounds` properties, and you add a `"fullscreen"` permision on the `manifest.json`.

```json
{
    ...
    "permissions": [
        ...
        "fullscreen"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What if I want to block it from running fullscreen at startup? On mac if I close the app when it was fullscreen, it will launch on fullscreen next time I run it. How can I prevent this? `chrome.app.window.create(
      'view/viewer.html',
      {
        id: 'presentation-viewer-'+pres_id,
        bounds: {width: 1024, height: 768},
        "resizable": false,
        state: "maximized"
      }`

Comment: @Devrim please create another question as your case is different. I can't help you at this moment, but I'm sure the Community will. :D

Comment: I have but the community seems like it's run out of ideas :D

Comment: @Devrim make a comment here with the link please, I'll try to help you soon ;)

Comment: Good luck :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296116/block-chrome-app-from-launching-fullscreen

Answer (score 6):

You can use the HTML5 Fullscreen API, which requires a user action:

```js
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen();
});
```

or the more "app-y" way using the AppWindow object, which doesn't require a user action:

```js
chrome.app.window.current().fullscreen();
```

Both need the `"fullscreen"` permission in the `manifest.json`.

Comment: Is the "fullscreen" permission still a thing? It isn't listed here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions

Answer (score 3):

I have got it working with below code

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    'width': 1024,
    'height': 768
},
function(win) {
    win.maximize();
});
});
```

Comment: Make that a win.fullscreen(), after adding "fullscreen" to    "permissions" array in `manifest.json`

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://plus.google.com/100132233764003563318/posts/2SuD7MVd8mG referring to recently landed changelist https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/12205002. You can lift sample code from either of those sources:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen();
});
```

Make sure in your manifest you're requesting the "fullscreen" permission and that you're testing on a sufficiently recent Chrome build (beta channel ought to have this feature by now, and dev definitely does).

Your question specifically refers to packaged apps, but in case anyone reading this answer missed this, **this will work only with Chrome packaged apps**.

Comment: Is this supposed to work in apps running on Windows? I'm not able to get my app to go full screen. Calling document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen() has no affect.

Answer (score 1):

main.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html',{},function(window) {
    window.fullscreen();
  });
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  ...
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["fullscreen"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Per BeardFist's comment, my original answer was wrong on two fronts. You can do this on a Chrome Extension (which this is tagged as), but probably not on a packaged app.

For **extensions** you can make it go fullscreen using the state:"fullscreen" option, which can be applied with `chrome.window.update`. The code below chains the creation of the window via `chrome.windows.create` with `chrome.window.update`. In my experiments you could not set the fullscreen state directly through the window creation.

```
chrome.windows.create(
  {url:"PATH/TO/POPUP"}, 
    function(newWindow) {
        chrome.windows.update(newWindow.id, {state:"fullscreen"})
});
```

Comment: You can definitely trigger fullscreen from an extension with `{state:"fullscreen"}`, but you cannot do it with a packaged app. In fact you have no access to `chome.windows` at all so this won't work either.

Comment: Thanks, the question's tag led me to believe that they were asking about a browser extension.

Comment: This question is no longer tagged as "Google-Chrome-Extension"

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag (i thought that tag was used for both). Still a good find! But still weird that you seem to be able to do less with packaged apps than extensions. Maybe i should switch.

Comment: No worries :). They have different use cases, so it might make sense for you to switch. Details?

Comment: Fullscreen media application where i want to be able to request a fullscreen from another device.

Comment: I can't tell whether the media application you have in mind could be implemented as an extension, but I do know you can trigger it to go fullscreen from another device by introducing a server as an intermediary.