# Chrome packaged app fullscreen 1px white (bottom and right)

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen, google-chrome-app, html5-fullscreen

I'm making a packaged app in Chrome. It needs to be fullscreen.
To achieve this I have setup the following permissions in manifest.json (v2):

```
"permissions": [
  "alwaysOnTopWindows",
  "fullscreen",
  ....
]
```

In my background js file I call the following function:

```
chrome.app.window.create('html/main.html', {
  'state': 'fullscreen',
},windowCreated);
```

The window is created fullscreen only there is a 1px line on the right of the screen and a 1px line on the bottom of the screen. I tried all kind of things with CSS, i.e. made the background-color of main.html black, but still the white lines remains. It seems it cannot be changed using CSS.

Has anyone encountered this and found a possible solution?

The OS is Win7 64bit, Chrome versions 42.0.2311.90 m

Comment: Fullscreen requires user consent and therefore cannot be open on `onLoad` eventlistener. It can only happen when user clicks on the link. See this one to implement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451888/how-can-i-make-a-chrome-packaged-app-which-runs-in-fullscreen-at-startup

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The screen opens 'fullscreen' just fine without any consent needed.

I have made a picture of the issue, see: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=9df6d16

Comment: I see. It seems you've filled in the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=478133). Could you please keep an eye on that since I do believe crbug.com is the best place to answer this kind of issue. There's no wrong with API implement.

Comment: Thanks for that! I didn't actually create the issue because i presumed that it was not a bug, but my incorrect use of the api.

I will follow this issue and update this thread accordingly